# Inject a GStreamer pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, extensibility

Suppose I have an application written with GStreamer that has a pipeline for processing video data. For simplicity let's assume it looks like this:

```
appsrc->identity->appsink
```

While application with this hardcoded pipeline provides some functionality, I could imagine that users of my application might want to replace `identity` element with arbitrarily complex pipelines (still having the interface with one sink and one source with defined capabilities). Does GStreamer provide any functionality that would allow injecting whole pipelines into my application? If the pipeline could be defined with `gst-launch` it would be great, but C code is also fine. Or do I need to resort to some generic mechanisms for writing plugins?

Comment: dd you try gst-python? It is also easier to use

Comment: From what it seems you can indeed just call `gst-launch` from your application, or call  [`gst_parse_launch()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=py#gst_parse_launch) with the user-inputted string